# Get MAX value from a TOP number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following MS SQL Query

```
select top 10 RegisterTime
from  orderNotifications
order by RegisterTime asc
```

How can I get the max `RegisterTime` of that query ?

I have tried this

```
select max(RegisterTime) in (
    select top 10 RegisterTime
    from  orderNotifications
    order by RegisterTime asc
)
```

But I am getting

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'in'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the
> keyword 'order'.

Comment: is registertime a datetime?

Comment: yes...it is a datetime

Comment: change `in` to `from`

Comment: @kostyan you also have to alias the subquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your `TOP 10` query a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(RegisterTime)
FROM (SELECT TOP 10 RegisterTime
      FROM orderNotifications
      ORDER BY RegisterTime
      )sub
```

Comment: Goat that works...but what is the need for the "sub" at the end of the main select ? why is it needed ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia SQL Server requires that subqueries be aliased, so I chose `sub` as my generic subquery alias.

Comment: @MauricioGracia 'sub' is an alias as stated in the comments for the question. It's needed because the subquery in the parenthesis is essentially a temporary table made in the query and to access it you need to name it.

Comment: Mauricio you may be more used to seeing it written )AS sub, either are perfectly functional as you noted.